# Как правильно написать правило для jquery validation?

Tags: jquery, валидация

Здравствуйте.

В общем, есть метод, проверяющий количество введенных символов:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("exactlength", function(value, element, param) {
        return this.optional(element) || value.length == param;
    }, jQuery.format("Please enter exactly {0} characters."));
```

Как правильно изменить метод, чтобы я мог ставить проверку сразу на две длины? То есть, либо количество символов 10, либо 15.